# Netcat anomaly in VMWare/Cygwin/Sockets environment

Tags: sockets, cygwin, vmware, netcat

I'm happily running Ubuntu Linux in a VMWare box hosted on XP.

My Linux application opens up your basic server socket port, to which I connect netcat (nc) as a client to listen in on the traffic I'm putting on that socket for the "real" clients. All's well.

However, when I open up a Cygwin shell on the XP side and run nc from there it appears to be unable to connect to my application's server socket.

To verify connectivity, though, if I run nc as a server (`nc -l -p 3694`) in the Linux/VMWare environment, nc on Cygwin has no trouble connecting to it and transferring data back and forth (the IP address is not localhost, it's the one assigned by DHCP).

To summarize:

```
Linux App      --  Linux nc  : Works
Linux App      --  Cygwin nc : Does not work
Linux nc (svr) --  Cygwin nc : Works
```

Comment: Have you tried using wireshark to compare the ip packets to see how they differ?

Answer (score 0):

Which [netcat code](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2002-09/msg00174.html) are you using?  At least one variant has known issues...

Comment: I'm getting netcat from the standard Ubuntu and Cygwin distributions.

nc -h shows:
  Linux:  [v1.10-36]
  Cygwin: [v1.10]

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have the guest network set to NAT and therefore things can't connect to something listening in the VM?